# React Native: 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react3.PropTypes.bool')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have recently tried to export my react native project to expo. Although, it had updated react-native, and now get an error of 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react3.PropTypes.bool')'

[image: Error message]

I have looked to solve this and found that I need to import proptypes - `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` which ive added in all my scripts, still the error message persists. Moreover, I dont use any proptypes, so I dont get why i would get this error in the first place.

If you would like to take a look at the proj, please do - https://github.com/rasselll/probs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clearly mentioned in the log and is due to `react-native-view-transformer` library.

The library still uses the `PropTypes` package from `react`. Since your `react` version is higher that `v15.5` therefore it is giving an error.

[Here's](https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-view-transformer/blob/master/library/transform/ViewTransformer.js) a file from the package that is still using the deprecated version of `propTypes`

Comment: whats solution then?